# Startup application on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, webapps, startup-applications

I am looking for a startup app (which opens right after the user log in) on ubuntu 20.04.
If it matters, this app will show a tutorial, ideally presented via a slide show codded in html/CSS.
Is already aware of an existing tool for this?

Comment: Since you want HTML/CSS, are you averse to using an ordinary web browser? [Triggering a script at login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login) that launches the browser to your slide show (and does other tasks) is trivial and well-documented.

Comment: Your question is a bit ambiguous with my reading. I'm not sure if you want an app of some kind or if you just want to know how to start your already existing application. If you just want to autostart an application, [here's a handy guide](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-autostart-applications-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can definitively launch firefox, however how can I set it up to open a particular HTML file, rather than the home page already set up in there? If possible I wold like to remove the URL address bar and the favorites in the browser too.